# WiFi Adapter keeps disconnecting

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with a network adapter D-Link DWA-137.

Until recently it worked properly but suddenly every few seconds ubuntu says i have no network adapter connected and then after a few seconds a recognizes the adapter again. this makes internet unusable.

Oddly, when i started using usb tethering with my phone to connect to the internet I noticed that while I am tethering my adapter suddenly works fine. I can't seem to wrap my head around why that is happening.

does anyone have any idea how to solve this?